# Loading Mp3 files takes time in Marshmallow and above versions

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-permissions

I am trying to load mp3 files in my recyclerview using AsyncTask. The files are properly loaded in android versions lollipop and below.But from Marshmallow,loading takes a quite along time.In lollipop i directly call my AsyncTask.execute() but from Marshmallow onwards i need to write like this,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);

            } else {
                myTask.execute();
          }

        }
```

If i remove the above code and just write myTask.execute(); in onCreate and test in lollipop and below it works fine.Please help me why it takes such a long time in Marshmallow and above?

Comment: Use method tracing in Android Studio to determine where your time is being spent. I am fairly confident that `checkSelfPermssion()` and `requestPermissions()` are not the slow parts.

Comment: @CommonsWare How to use method tracing?

Comment: You could start with [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-methodtrace.html) and work from there.